# Privilege to edit answer but not to comment

Tags: support, comments, privileges, edits

How is it that I am allowed to edit an answer (revise and improve this post) but not comment on it ? (I currently have 31 reputation and have Supporter, Editor and Teacher badges).

Is this a bug? Or have I not correctly understood the how the privileges work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't edit an answer.

You can only **suggest** an edit. It will be reviewed (by users with at least 2k rep) and either approved or rejected.

We have a review system (for closing, deleting, editing posts) that is only visible to users having the needed amount of rep.

Comment: [juergen-d](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172011/juergen-d) Thank you!

Comment: @RavindraHV The proper way to reply to a user is to use the `@<user>` notation. This way the referred user will get a notification. Note that the question/answer owner will always be notified. See [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) Also, you don't need to comment "Thank you", just upvote the question/answer/comment when you have the privilege :)

Comment: Ha! I can just see it coming, a feature request to allow sub-50-rep users to suggest comments, and a Suggested Comments review queue. :) I actually don't necessarily think that would be such a bad idea, and it would probably reduce the frequency of comments-as-answers or comments suggested as edits, but there's one thing I have to warn against emphatically: **NO** +2 rep for having a suggested comment approved!!!!

Comment: @AlvinWong  In case of 'juergen d' I did not (and still do not) get an auto-suggest as i got it in your case. So I thought it was not working in 'meta'. Hence the approach. I get an auto suggest for 'AdiInbar' as well but not 'juergen d'.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, all of your edits will go through a review queue to make sure they are valid. Users with 2000 reputation or more can review suggested edits. You need 2000 reputation to make edits without them being reviewed.

Second of all, comments are second-class citizens. We want to focus on the actual **questions** and **answers**; that's what makes us a Q&A site and not a forum. This is why you can suggest edits even at 1 reputation, while you need 50 reputation to comment.

[Here is more information about the privileges of the Stack Exchange network.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: [Doorknob](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/180276/doorknob) I visited the page before asking but it still was not clear. Hence the question. Thanks though.